# Jupyter Notebook codes are all defaulting to an uppercase

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Jupyter Notebook codes are all  defaulting to an uppercase and could someone shed light on how to configure the fonts

Comment: here is a sample of the code:

Comment: Are you wanting to change the font within a markdown cell? And can you give us an example of what is being defaulted to uppercase?